# Prediction not zero when model fitted without an intercept term

Tags: r, regression

```
y <- c(60.323,61.122,60.171,61.187,63.221,63.639,64.989,63.761,66.019,67.857,68.169,66.513,68.655,69.564,69.331,70.551)
x1 <- c(83,88.5,88.2,89.5,96.2,98.1,99,100,101.2,104.6,108.4,110.8,112.6,114.2,115.7,116.9)

mod <- lm(y - 1 ~ x1) # fit a model without intercept 

plot(x1, y)
abline(mod, col = "red")
```

Predict for x1 = 0

```
dat <- data.frame(x1 = 0)
predict(mod, newdata = dat)
```

Why the prediction is not zero. I thought when we fit a model without intercept,
the model should predict zero when the predictor value is zero.

Comment: If you look at summary(mod) you clearly see a line marked Intercept. This is a clue. I think you meant to type y ~ x - 1 perhaps.

Comment: I agree with @mdewey: This is a question about a typographical error in software code, not about statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linear model like $y=a+\beta*x$ *always* has an intercept because the intercept is simply the predicted value for $y$ if $x=0$, i.e. $y=a$ (where $a$ can be $0$ though). What you were doing is simply subtracting $1$ from the estimated intercept, so your model was $y=(a-1)+\beta*x$. You can easily force the intercept to be $0$ in R like this:

```
mod2 <- lm(y ~ 0 + x1) # fit a model without intercept 
mod2
plot(x1, y, ylim = c(0,100), xlim = c(0,115))
abline(mod2, col = "red")

dat <- data.frame(x1 = 0)
predict(mod2, newdata = dat)
```

However, I don't think that the linear model with intercept at $0$ is a good idea here. All your observations are far from $0$ and your residuals become quite large.

Comment: lm(y ~ -1 + x1) also fits a model with no intercept in R. The OP just has a typo/error in their code in that they put -1 on the left hand side instead of the right, so they are predicting (y-1) as a function of x1 and an intercept.